# How to check if customers subscribe a servie?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm creating a page for admins that shows if a customer is subscribed to a monthly subscription. Is there a way, using Stripe's API, to check if 50 customers have paid subscriptions at once?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to check if 50 specific customers have paid subscriptions at once with a single API call using the Stripe API.

Assuming you have a list of Customer ids, you can implement a loop to list all Subscriptions for a particular `customer`, `price` and `status`. See https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list.